# Installation of Wand fails because of imagemagick linking error

Tags: python, imagemagick, symlink, wand, magickwand

I want to use the python package wand and installed it with

```
pip install Wand
```

but when I run the script I get the error

ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install freetype imagemagick

so I followed the instruction

```
$ brew install freetype imagemagick
Warning: freetype 2.8.1 is already installed
Warning: imagemagick 7.0.7-10 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link imagemagick` to link this version.
```

and again followed the instruction

```
$ brew link imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-10... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7 is not writable.
```

does anybody know what this is about? I have never seen such an issue and google does seem to show any useful results...

EDIT: Here is what I get when I try to remove the package and reinstall

```
$ brew install ImageMagick --with-freetype  
Warning: imagemagick: this formula has no --with-freetype option so it will be ignored!
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/imagemagick-7.0.7-10.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/xflorian/Library/Caches/Homebrew/imagemagick-7.0.7-10.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring imagemagick-7.0.7-10.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7 is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link imagemagick
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-10: 1,523 files, 23.1MB

$ brew link imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-10... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7 is not writable.
```

Comment: Search stackoverflow.com. You will find solutions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105000/problems-with-homebrew-on-yosemite. I don't use Homebrew, but that looks like the same issue you have.

Comment: your link just suggested to remove the brew package and reinstall... I tried that, it gives the same error

Comment: I have seen other answers on this forum that have you install ImageMagick --with freetype or something like that. Search the forum for other similar questions about homebrew and freetype.

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265131/cant-install-imagemagick-and-rmagick-on-osx-mavericks/25529025#25529025

Comment: try: `brew uninstall ImageMagick` then `brew install ImageMagick --with-freetype

Comment: Here is another link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537011/imagemagick-issue-on-lion-installed-with-homebrew

Comment: I added some more information above... just reinstalling gives the same error

Comment: Did you uninstall wand, ImageMagick and free type and then install ImageMagick  with freetype or install freetype and then install ImageMagick. Then if ImageMagick shows freetype listed when you do `magick -version`, then install Wand. Sorry this is beyond me as I do not use Homebrew.

Comment: Here is another reference to using --force and other solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624778/imagemagick-jpeg-decode-delegate-missing-with-os-x-homebrew-install. And another about linking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006518/rmagick-installation-fails-to-build-native-extension/23459613#23459613

Comment: if I follow these suggestions it always comes back to the symlink not working Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-10... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7 is not writable.